# How can I add a lot of Buttons to the tkinter Frame efficiently?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to add 10 buttons to Tkinter, named One to Ten. I basically just used the brute force method, adding each button as I went, in the **init** function of my application's class. It works, but I want to minimize the code used, to be more efficient, such as using a data structure to hold all the buttons.

I was thinking of using a `buttonBox` to hold all the buttons in, but I was not sure if I could manipulate the placement via `grid()` to place the buttons how I wanted.

```
self.one = Button(frame, text="One", command=self.callback)
self.one.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=1, pady=1)

self.two = Button(frame, text="Two", command=self.callback)
self.two.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

self.three = Button(frame, text="Three", command=self.callback)
self.three.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)

# ...

self.ten = Button(frame, text="Ten", command=self.callback)
self.ten.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, row=1, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)
```

Can anyone show me a way to make this more efficient, such as a data structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of naming the buttons `self.one`, `self.two`, etc., it would be more convenient to refer to them by indexing a list, such as `self.button`.

If the buttons do *different* things, then you just have to explicitly
associate buttons with callbacks. For example:

```
name_callbacks=(('One',self.callback_one),
                ('Two',self.callback_two),
                ...,
                ('Ten',self.callback_ten))
self.button=[]
for i,(name,callback) in enumerate(name_callbacks):
    self.button.append(Button(frame, text=name, command=callback))
    row,col=divmod(i,5)
    self.button[i].grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
```

If the buttons all do *similar* things, then one callback may suffice to service them all. Since the callback itself can't take arguments, you can setup a callback factory to pass the arguments in through a closure:

```
def callback(self,i): # This is the callback factory. Calling it returns a function.
    def _callback():
        print(i) # i tells you which button has been pressed.
    return _callback

def __init__(self):
    names=('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten')
    self.button=[]
    for i,name in enumerate(names):
        self.button.append(Button(frame, text=name, command=self.callback(i+1)))
        row,col=divmod(i,5)
        self.button[i].grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I had to change it to "self.button.append()" so it didn't cause an IndexError. And the bottom line I changed to self.button[i].grid(), instead of self.one.grid(). It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Only one thing... how would you get the buttons to callback different commands?

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the buttons properties in a dict, and then loop on it to create your buttons, here is an example:

```
buttons = {
    'one': {'sticky': W+E+N+S, 'padx': 1, 'pady': 1},
    'two': {'sticky': W+E+N+S, 'row': 0, 'column': 1, 'padx': 1, 'pady': 1},
    'three': {'sticky': W+E+N+S, 'row': 0, 'column': 2, 'padx': 1, 'pady': 1}
}
for b in buttons:
    button = Button(frame, text=b.title(), command=self.callback)
    button.grid(**buttons[b])
    setattr(self, b, button)
```

This would also allow you to easily add new buttons if needed.